# print content linked list

Tags: c

I know how I can print the information of an list but the content of my file is is appearing inverted!

```
void imprimi_tabuleiro(Tabuleiro* tabu)
{
    Tabuleiro* aux; // p auxiliar a prcorrer o tabuleiro
    for (aux = tabu; aux != NULL ; aux = aux ->Prox)
    {
        printf("\n%s %s %s %d\n ", aux ->casa , aux ->proxcasa , aux ->regracasa , aux ->energia);
    }
}
```

For example my file is :

```
1 2 0 0

3 4 5 7 


1 9 0 4
```

and when i run the code appear

```
1 9 0 4


3 4 5 7


1 2 0 0
```

How can i change that?

Comment: (1) use a doubly linked list and print from the tail back to the head. (2) walk your linked list pushing all item pointers into a stack (which is another linked list, btw) and pop them all off the stack, printing each one as you go.

Comment: You are passing in the tail pointer. (aux = aux ->Prox) is a clue. If you wanted start->end print, it would be aux = aux->next

Comment: Anon , aux = aux -> prox is tha same as aux = aux -> next , in portuguese Prox is the same as NEXT ! : )

Comment: You could add to the end of the list for your insert.  It may take a bit of time, but the elements would be in the order you read them in and then would print out as such.  But it does involve transversing the list to get to the end to add the item you have read.

Comment: Please keep the `->` operator in contact with both its operands; it binds very tightly and should not have any space around it (and similarly with `.`).  So, you should write `aux->casa`, `aux->proxcasa`, `aux->regracasa`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is probably that you have an single linked list, and when you add entries to the list you add them to the *head* of the list.

A solution is to keep track of the tail of the list, and then add there instead.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you appear to have a doubly-linked list, it looks like you're inserting the entries at the front, not the tail of the list.  That would certainly account for the reverse ordering.

Can you show your read and insert code?

Answer (score 0):

I got it !

```
abuleiro* inserir_tabuleiro(Tabuleiro* Tab, char casa[] , char proxcasa[] , char regracasa[], int energia)
```

{

```
Tabuleiro* Novo  = cria(casa , proxcasa ,  regracasa,  energia); //cria novo no





Tabuleiro* anterior = NULL; //ponteiro p o anterior
Tabuleiro* p= Tab; // p percorrer








while(p!=NULL ){



            anterior = p ;
            p = p->Prox;




}



if(anterior==NULL)
{
    Novo->Prox = Tab;

    Tab = Novo;
}
else
{
    Novo->Prox = anterior->Prox;
    anterior->Prox = Novo;
}





return Tab;
```

}

Thank u all!!